# Error posting to IBM Connections 4.5 activity stream

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

Using a browser REST client to POST to the activity stream at e.g.

```
https://connectionsww.demos.ibm.com/connections/opensocial/basic/rest/activitystreams/@me/@all
```

...with the settings prescribed in [IBM Connections OpenSocial API > POSTing new events](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.5+API+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=POSTing_new_events_ic45&content=pdcontent)

...results in the following response:

```
<error xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">
    <code>403</code>
    <message>You are not authorized to perform the requested action.</message>
    <trace></trace>
</error>
```

What am I missing?

This same approach works nicely on IBM Connections 4.0.

Which setting needs 'switching on'?

Comment: And You authenticated with the REST client? If so, what errors are in your log file - SystemOut.log

Comment: Yes, I'm authenticated in a separate browser tab. I see no errors in SystemOut.log ; Should I  increase the logging levels too?

Comment: Switch to a Private Window. Launch the REST Client... What does the GET request on the same URL do?

Comment: GET on the same URL works fine - gives a JSON object: http://pastebin.com/E7knvSwn

Comment: strange... when you use the REST client do you get the Authorization: Basic Header?

Comment: Yes: http://i7.minus.com/jbk3HcZW1EAowI.png

Answer (score 1):

Try a URL like this... https://sbtdev.swg.usma.ibm.com:444/connections/opensocial/basic/rest/activitystreams/@me/@all

I added the Basic/Rest component, and it worked for me.

1 - Added URL https://sbtdev.swg.usma.ibm.com:444/connections/opensocial/basic/rest/activitystreams/@me/@all

2 - Changed Method to Post

3 - Added Content-Type: application/json

4 - Authentication -> Basic

5 - Logged IN

6 - Posted

[image: Rest Client Setup]

Answer (score 0):

Same thing here: 403 when I make an AJAX call to an IBM Connections 6.0 REST API url. Same error in Chrome, Firefox and IE11. When I open the same URL in a separate browser tab, everything works fine.

Comparing the http headers of both calls, and fiddling with Postman, the diference is the presence and value of the atribute `Origin`.

Seems that Connections allows calls from its own server. For example, when: `Origin: connections.mycompany.com`. 
It also allows calls when `Origin` is not defined, which happens when the url is called from a separate browser tab.

There is a doc at IBMs Support site that confirms this - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21999210. It also suggests a workaround that did the job for me: unsetting the `Origin` attribute in the IBM HTTP Server that is in front of your Connections instance. Add the lines below to the  `httpd.conf` file:

```
Header unset Origin
RequestHeader unset Origin
```

Comment: Format this please

Comment: Hi Prateek. Did some formatting above. Do you have an example of what you expect?

Comment: Please check [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and see good answers on stackoverflow. Your answer is better now